Code that only works on one platform. Unity 2d
I wrote this code, but there is one problem. This code works differently on different platforms. On Android it works without errors. But on PC it gives an error Assets\Scripts\HingeMovement.cs(119,2): error CS1513: } expected. What should I do please tell me.
This code was designed to hook onto objects and use them to move.
On Android
On PC
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HingeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool _grabbing;
    public LineRenderer lr;
    public GameObject button;

    GameObject FindNearest()
    {
        GameObject[] hinges;
        hinges = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("hinge");
        GameObject closest = null;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;

        foreach (GameObject go in hinges)
        {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance; 
            }
        }
        return closest; 
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        lr.startWidth = 0.08f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.08f;
        lr.startColor = Color.yellow;
        lr.endColor = Color.yellow;

#if UNITY_STANDALONE
        button.SetActive(false);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _grabbing = true; 
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            lr.positionCount = 2;
            GameObject closest = FindNearest();

            if (_grabbing)
            {
                lr.SetPosition(1, closest.transform.position);
                closest.GetComponentInChildren<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody =
                    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody2D>();
                _grabbing = false; 
            }
            lr.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            GameObject[] hinges;
            hinges = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("hinge");

            foreach (GameObject go in hinges)
            {
                lr.positionCount = 0;
                go.GetComponentInChildren<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody = null; 
            }
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) //ЛКМ + ПКМ
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 0);
        }
        }
        

#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        button.SetActive(true);
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            _grabbing = true; 
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            lr.positionCount = 2;
            GameObject closest = FindNearest();

            if (_grabbing)
            {
                lr.SetPosition(1, closest.transform.position);
                closest.GetComponentInChildren<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody =
                    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody2D>();
                _grabbing = false; 
            }
            lr.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            GameObject[] hinges;
            hinges = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("hinge");

            foreach (GameObject go in hinges)
            {
                lr.positionCount = 0;
                go.GetComponentInChildren<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody = null; 
            }
        }
    }
        public void PhoneRestart()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 0);
        }
#endif
}

I think it's the placement of the words #if UNITY_STANDALONE, #elif UNITY_ANDROID and #endif.
I need this code to work on these two platforms

formatting of code really helps. It looks like your endif is supposed to be inside update, given thats where you start it.. despite the formatting it looks like the standalone ends update, but that if neither of those 2 (standalone and android) apply you're update has no end }

The problem is here:
    }
        public void PhoneRestart()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 0);
        }
#endif
}

You put the #endif wrong and the the } is actually from the class. Count the ending braces and retry the #if enclosure.
